# SQL join on multiple columns delete duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried looking for an answer to this but unfortunately can't find one. I'm very new to SQL. Maybe someone can help?

I'd like to join 3 tables together to see a list of book titles and the names of the category they're in:

1. Table 1 has a list of book titles and book IDs
2. Table 2 has a list of book IDs and category IDs
3. Table 3 has a list of category IDs and category names

I managed to do this using join:

```
select backend.t1.title, backend.t3.category_name
FROM backend.t1
join backend.t2 on bms.t1.book_id = backend.t2.category_id 
join backend.t3 on backend.t2.category_id = backend.t3.category_id;
```

However, the result has duplicate book titles in it. How do I remove duplicate book titles? Category names can be duplicated, as often several titles will be in the same category. Every solution I've tried has cleared the table of both duplicate titles and category names, so it's been a very short list!

Thank you! Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The `join` between t1 and t2 should be `bms.t1.book_id = backend.t2.book_id`.  Did you try `select distinct`?

Comment: say one book is related to 2 different categories. now you are getting "book1+category1" and "book1+category2". what did you expect to see?
PS it's normal behavior for such a case.

Comment: On your first `JOIN`, why do you use `t1.book_id = t2.category_id` for your join condition?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Based on the logically assumption that a book can have multiple categories, order your results by title, category.  Then ensure the combination of title/category is unique, not just the title itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT backend.t1.title, backend.t3.category_name
FROM backend.t1
JOIN backend.t2 ON bms.t1.book_id = backend.t2.book_id 
JOIN backend.t3 ON backend.t2.category_id = backend.t3.category_id;
```

Your join from table 2 back to table 1 should be joined by book_id as you are looking to find the the categories associated with each book.

Some things to consider: Table 2 that contains your 'link' from your book IDs to your category IDs is most likely a many-to-one table as in there can be multiple categories for each book_id.  If this is the case then by joining on this table you could see the same book title multiple times due to that book having more than one category.  The data being returned would represent each book out of table 1 and all of the categories it is 'linked' to in table 2.  Table 3 is most definitely a one-to-one table as in each category_id is unique and is simply a lookup to the name of the category.

Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem perfectly. As I mentioned above, I'm quite new to all this stuff...